# Flipping SKSpriteNode texture after collision makes it looping

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am learning some SpriteKit. I am trying to do this: On tap move node right --> On right wall collision flip Node's texture -->  Change direction and repeat if on left wall.

The problem is that after collision it is going to loop the image flip. What could cause this?

I am moving the SKSPriteNode on touch:

```
 moveAction = SKAction.moveBy(x: 100, y: 0, duration: 1)
 node.run(moveAction, withKey: "Right")
 node.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
 node.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 40, dy: 130))
```

This is how I detect collision:

```
if (firstBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCatagory.node == PhysicsCatagory.node &&
            secondBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCatagory.RightWall == PhysicsCatagory.RightWall) {

            direction = "Left"
            rotate()
        }else if (firstBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCatagory.RightWall == PhysicsCatagory.RightWall &&
            secondBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCatagory.node == PhysicsCatagory.node) {

            direction = "Left"
            rotate()
        }
```

And like this I flip the node:

```
func rotate(){
        if direction == "Right"{
            node.xScale = node.xScale * -1
            updateScoreAndChangeBackgroundColor()
        }else{
            node.xScale = node.xScale * -1
            updateScoreAndChangeBackgroundColor()
        }
    }
```

I understand that it collides all the time as long as the direction hasen't changed and I am doing it on click. But how and should I bounce the node back to prevent this?

Comment: What does "it is going to loop the image flip" mean?

Comment: @0x141E it does things multiple times. For example if you add score on collision, instead of adding one, it adds 3. It adds the score as long as the collision stops. And flips the image as long as the collision stops.

Comment: Perhaps you can pass `direction` (for example "Left") into the `rotate` method and flip the character and increment the score only if parameter and the current direction aren't the same and set `direction` variable in the `rotate` method.

Comment: @0x141E check the image to see what I am talking about. I am sure the thing is with logic so I am trying your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
func rotate(newDirection:String) {
    if newDirection != direction {
        node.xScale = node.xScale * -1
        updateScoreAndChangeBackgroundColor()
        direction = newDirection
    }
}
```

and call rotate with

```
rotate (newDirection: "Left")
```

or this

```
rotate (newDirection: "Right")
```